# ios/Android targeted push notifications in AIR app

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I was wondering if it is possible to have multiple custom push notifications setup in a single AIR App.

What I am trying to do is allow users to setup custom alerts based on information they would like to receive for example say user 1 would like to know when new actions or drama movies are released on DVD, user 2 would like to know when new comedies are released, user 3 would like to know when any new movie is released.

This is a simple example and there are possibly 1000's of options (postcode/zip information).

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically, there's nothing that wouldn't allow you to do this.
The implementation is mostly backend related though, let me just quickly draft a design for that here;

1. The user's device registers for push notifications at your backend service.
2. Your service takes the user's id stores in a DB and passes the device token to the corresponding push notification server.
3. Once the registration is completed, the user selects what items he'd like to get notified of (naturally your backend service has to know this information as well to store it in the DB).
4. As soon as a new action movie (or whatever kind of information the user registered for) is available, your service looks in the DB what users registered for that kind of movies and sends a message via push.

So a simple database and some server side scripting will get you going.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. That's the approach I thought would be best but thought I would ask before getting my hands dirty coding.

Comment: You're welcome. Just for clarification, both your backend and air app need to handle the different notification implementations. That is, the server has to communicate with Apple's APNS and Google's GCM. That doesn't affect the basic strategy, though. Just make sure to also store the device type in your database so that you can address the correct notification service. Good luck with the Android client side, though. Due to the native support of APNS in AIR, the iOS implementation is very straightforward, but I've yet to find a working Android push ANE. If you know one, please let me know.

Comment: Hi there, thanks again for the information. It help set things up. The extensions I am using are http://labs.distriqt.com/native-extensions#push-notifications. I have not yet tested the Android version but the iOS was very easy to implement.

Comment: @KerePuki, I've tried that extension as well (for Android that is, no extension needed for iOS). It worked, though I find the mechanism to show notifications very disturbing on Android. Since there is no default OS notification message popup, the ANE uses it's own popup which I found particularly limited to the developers needs as since they didn't make the extension fully customizable, it wasn't for me. I'm actually waiting for Adobe to implement Android push notifications natively in a future AIR release. Not sure when and if that is going to happen, though.